# XML files to ConfigMap yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there anyway to convert configuration files like xml to kubernetes configmap yaml file without using kubectl command ? Let’s say if I want to create xml files dynamically which in turn stored in git repo as configmap yaml and some operator can monitor for yaml changes and deploy it to the cluster.

Comment: Does this answer your quesion? https://medium.com/@dheeraj007tripathi/configmap-and-kubernetes-overriding-configuration-files-5db9e6da08c9  i.e. embedding the XML file in a ConfigMap?

Answer (score 2):

> configuration files like xml to kubernetes configmap yaml file without using kubectl command

Sure, because the only thing `kubectl` does with `yaml` is immediately convert it to `json` and then `POST` (or `PUT` or whatever) to the kubernetes api with a `content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8` header (you can watch that take place via `kubectl --v=100 create -f my-thing.yaml`)

So, the answer to your question is to use your favorite programming language that has libraries for json (or the [positively amazing jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq#readme)), package the XML as necessary, the use something like [kube-applier](https://github.com/box/kube-applier#readme) to monitor and roll out the change:

```py
# coding=utf-8
import json
import sys

result = {
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "ConfigMap",
  # etc etc
  "data": [],
}
for fn in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(fn) as fh:
       body = fh.read()
    data.append({fn: body})
json.dump(result, sys.stdout)  # or whatever
```